# Automated test case generation from UML/OCL model in eclipse

Tags: java, uml, modeling, ocl

I am doing model based testing and i've modeled my application with UML diagrams and also wrote all the constrains for testing using OCL, and i was wondering if there is a tool or plugin for eclipse which helps to generate testcases from UML/OCL model which can be used for black-box testing. (thanks in advance)

'
@Christian thanks for your reply and below is part of the my OCL expressions

```
post: numberOfTrials = numberOfTrials@pre + 1
and if userPin = customer.card.pin and numberOfTrials <= 3
then pinAccepted and result = PinResult::Correct
else not pinAccepted
and if numberOfTrials <= 3
then result = PinResult::Wrong
else result = PinResult::Abort
endif
endif
context ATMController::withdraw(amount:Real) : Boolean
pre: pinAccepted
post: if (amount <= customer.account.balance)
then customer.account.balance =
customer.account.balance@pre - amount
and result = true
else customer.account.balance =
customer.account.balance@pre
and result = false
endif
```

'

Comment: Can you give an example for your OCL expressions? Do they check the model on instance level? If yes, simply generating code with EMF could be enough.

Comment: @Christian i added example of OCL expression i used.

Answer (score 0):

As your query seems to handle instances of Model classes you could generate EMF (ecore) from your org.eclipse.uml model (create genmodel and select .uml-file as source) and then use Eclipse OCL to execute your queries like described here: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.emf.query.doc/tutorials/oclQueryTutorial.html

Comment: Thank you @Christian i will try your suggestion